# Full calendar months between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, date-arithmetic

I have two dates (let's say 2020-09-15 and 2020-12-10) in a SQL Server database and I need to find out how many full calendar months exist between both dates.

In my example the output should be "2" as there October and November are the only full calendar months.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered a calendar table? Alternatively a Tally or a rCTE (though slower than a Tally) would work.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
select t.*, 
    datediff(month, start_date, end_date) 
        - case when day(end_date) <  day(start_date) then 1 else 0 end 
        as month_diff
from mytable t
```

`datediff()` counts the number of end of month boundaries that exist within the two dates. We can then adjust the result by substracting `1` if the day of the month of the end date is less than that of the start date.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fbaefecd9892e564165069d9e98be3e6)**:

```
select t.*, 
    datediff(month, start_date, end_date) 
        - case when day(end_date) <  day(start_date) then 1 else 0 end 
        as month_diff
from (values 
    ('2020-09-15', '2020-12-10'), 
    ('2020-09-15', '2020-12-17')
) t(start_date, end_date)
```

```
start_date | end_date   | month_diff
:--------- | :--------- | ---------:
2020-09-15 | 2020-12-10 |          2
2020-09-15 | 2020-12-17 |          3
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick help, but maybe not exact what I am looking for as your second example (2020-09-15 to 2020-12-17) should also show a diff of "2" as there are still only two full calendar months in there (2020-10-01 to 2020-10-31 and 2020-11-01 to 2020-11-30). I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @pal: in that case just `datediff(month, start_date, end_date)  - 1` should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SQL Server's datetime functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to check if `date1` is the first day of the month or not and if `date2` is the last day of the month or not, so you can calculate the difference:

```
WITH cte(date1, date2) AS (
  SELECT '2020-09-15', '2020-12-10' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-09-01', '2020-12-10' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-09-15', '2020-12-31' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-09-15', '2020-10-31' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-09-15', '2020-09-30' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-09-01', '2020-09-30'
)
SELECT *, 
       DATEDIFF(
         MONTH,
         CASE DAY(date1) 
           WHEN 1 THEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, date1)
           ELSE EOMONTH(date1)
         END,
         CASE 
           WHEN DAY(date2) = DAY(EOMONTH(date2)) THEN date2
           ELSE DATEADD(MONTH, -1, EOMONTH(date2))
         END
       ) diff_in_full_months  
FROM cte
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bc337d78a34ab196ed1ebd16cee47c94).
Results:

```
> date1      | date2      | diff_in_full_months
> :--------- | :--------- | ------------------:
> 2020-09-15 | 2020-12-10 |                   2
> 2020-09-01 | 2020-12-10 |                   3
> 2020-09-15 | 2020-12-31 |                   3
> 2020-09-15 | 2020-10-31 |                   1
> 2020-09-15 | 2020-09-30 |                   0
> 2020-09-01 | 2020-09-30 |                   1
```